# babel - es2015 and es2017 preset not working together

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I have two js files : `play.js` and `myStore.js`.

I want to import code from `myStore.js` into `play.js` and use it there. I'm using `es2015` plugin for the import, But it makes my `es2017` friendly code fail, even though I have `es2017` setup.

**play.js**:

```
import G from '../functions/myStore.js'; // import needs es2015

// this works with es2017, but not when es2015 is also included
for(k in [1,2,3]) console.log(k)
```

**myStore.js**

```
var G = {}
export default G
```

**Output**: 
 If I did not `import` anything, and just used the `es2017` preset, this would run fine, but using `es2015` along with `es2017` makes this fail as below:

```
for (k in [1, 2, 3]) {
     ^
ReferenceError: k is not defined
```

I'm executing this from terminal via `npm start` . Here's my **package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "play.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "babel-node play.js"
  },
  "author": "Somjit",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015-node5": "^1.2.0",
    "babel-preset-es2017": "^6.22.0"
  }
}
```

and my **babel.rc**:

```
{ "presets": ["es2015", "es2017"] }
```

Comment: Saying you 'can't import code' is a little vague - what happens when you try? Do you get an error? The more info you can give us, the better we'll be able to help :)

Comment: Well, I'm not sure, but I think that `babel-preset-es2017` does not support imports/exports. You need `babel-preset-es2015`. Other things looks fine

Comment: @JoeClay it gives a really verbose 45 lines of error, but most of it says like "make sure you have the latest versions installed" which is useless.

Comment: @disstruct so what happens when es2015 does not support your code?

Comment: @Somjit babel allows you to use new js syntax features (like `import`, `export`). Babel library is divided in several parts (presets). Each part allows you to use particular features. To use `import`, `export` syntax you need `babel-preset-es2015`, but you are using another part of Babel library (babel-preset-es2017).

Comment: @disstruct in that case, can I use multiple presets together?

Comment: @Somjit Sure. The idea of dividing the library is to give you the opportunity to use only presets that you need

Comment: Oooh, yeah - the ES2017 preset *only* includes the features added in the ES2017 spec (which there weren't that many). ES2015 was where all the juicy stuff like imports got added.

Comment: Soo.. how to use es2015 for import, and then es2017 for the latest stuff??

Comment: @Somjit Just use all presets you need, and Babel will figure out how to transpile your code. In you case run `npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015` and change your `npm start` script to `babel-node play.js --presets es2015 es2017`

Comment: @disstruct I see a `presets` option for the package.json file, So if i put in all the presets I need there, how does the start script change? And btw, thanks for the above info! I'm starting to get it now!

Comment: I don't  use `presets` option in my `package.json` file. The common practice is to use .babelrc file instead. Create file `.babelrc` in your root directory. In that file you need to write `{"presets": ["es2015", "es2017"] }` After this change you start script to just `babel-node play.js`

Comment: you should define your variable `k` using `let` like this `for(let key in [1, 2, 3])` I think it is not an issue of presets its just js sintax (you need to declare variables)

Comment: But it works with es2017 (no need to declare syntax). Edited the question further to make things more clear.

Comment: Ok. My short answer would be... 1) If you look to the docs  of babel-preset-es2017 babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2017 you'll see that it supports only two features. You have not this features in your code. So babel don't use this preset while reading your code. 2) If you run your code without es2015 it allows you to declare variables without `var` (because you can do this in js). But when you use this preset Babel reads your code and trows an Error because according to new js standarts you need to declare variables with `var`, `let` or `const`

Comment: @disstruct Ok! Can you please put together these in an answer? I'll accept it as the solution. Many Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. My short answer would be...

1) Babel reads your code and if it sees some new js feature it translate it to regular js by using presets. For example, if it sees `let a = 1` Babel uses `preset-es2015` (that knows what `let` is) and translate this line into `var a = 1` so your browser could understand this line.

2) If you look to the [docs](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2017) of babel-preset-es2017 you'll see that it supports only two features. You have not this features in your code. So babel don't use this preset while reading code that you've provided. So es2017 don't matter in your problem.

3) If you run your code without es2015 it allows you to declare variables without var (because you can do this in js without strict mode). But when you use this preset Babel reads your code and trows an Error because according to new js standarts you need to declare variables with var, let or const and can't just write `a = 1`;

Answer (score 1):

when I started with babel even small stuff where taking too much time to understand.
then I found this [tutorial](http://ccoenraets.github.io/es6-tutorial/) which helped me a lot.

Comment: Thanks for the link :)

Answer (score 0):

In Your case, absolutely your problem is not `babel-preset-es2017`. you must install `babel-plugin-transform-runtime` and put it in your `.babelrc` file as plugin.

installing:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-runtime
```

setting `.babelrc` file:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "es2017"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-runtime"
  ]
}
```